# jQuery not defined

Tags: php, functions, jquery

First off I know there are tons of other "jQuery is not defined" threads and I have gone through them all and can't seem to find a solution. Trying to add jQuery functionality to a custom made theme nav and I cannot seem to get around this problem. Code is working fine in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TonyTheOnly/h7xwcb8h/

But when I try to attempt this in my wordpress theme i get the error "jQuery is not defined"

Header

```
</head>

<body <?php body_class( $awesome_classes ); ?>>
    <div class="topBar">
        <img src="<?php header_image();?>" height="120px;" width="100px;" alt=""/ class="siteLogo">
    <div class="topBarMiddle">
        <p>español | ENGLISH</p>
        </div>
      <div class="topBarRight">  
        <nav>
        <a class="burger-nav"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
</div>
```

functions

```
<?php

function paramo_script_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/paramo.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/paramo.js', array('jQuery'), '1.0.0', true);


}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'paramo_script_enqueue');
function paramo_theme_setup() {

    add_theme_support('menus');

    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Primary Header Navigation');
    register_nav_menu('secondary', 'Footer Navigation');


}
add_action('init', 'paramo_theme_setup');

add_theme_support('custom-header');
```

jQuery

```
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/

jQuery(function () {
    "use strict";

    $(".burger-nav").on("click", function () {

        $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time!

Comment: Note that if you fix this there'll be a second issue where `$` is undefined, it should be `jQuery( "nav ul")` not `$( "nav ul" )`. You've also setup your initial function incorrectly, look into `jQuery(document).ready`

Comment: I want to add that you should always use document ready to be safe and use an anonymous function where you pass in jQuery to be mapped to $ combined with document ready. Like so: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dependencies argument of `wp_enqueue_script()` is case sensetive:

```
wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/paramo.js', array('jQuery'), '1.0.0', true);
```

That `array('jQuery')` needs to be `array( 'jquery' )`.

You can see the handles for bundled scripts on the documentation page for `wp_enqueue_script()`: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: There a few things similar to how a man feels when he realizes case sensitivity caused all of his anguish. haha Thank you! Also was doing the $(document).ready(function) and changed it to the wp shortcode jQuery(document).ready(function){

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment quite yet but it's a good idea to move away from using the ready method to load your jQuery script. Start your WordPress scripts with `jQuery(function(){code here});` jQuery 3.x deprecates the formerly acceptable `jQuery(document).ready(function()....`. [More info here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Thanks, after about 30 minutes of searching I found this answer, which finally explains why my JQuery code wasn't working.

Comment: @clayRay Glad it helped!